# Why are the buttons in this toolbar not firing their target actions?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, selector

I've been banging my head against the wall for an hour.  The buttons created by this code ought to fire, and they don't.

```
-(void)createToolbar {

[self.bar removeFromSuperview];
self.bar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, TOOLBAR_HEIGHT)];
[self.bar setTintColor:self.userInfo.screenColorTrans];
[self.bar setTranslucent:YES];
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //It's the buttons send, trashButt, and editButt that appear and that change color when pressed (so I know they're registering user interaction) but that don't actually execute their methods.

UIBarButtonItem *send = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(share)];
[send setStyle : UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:Nil];
if (self.ghhaiku.isUserHaiku) {
    UIBarButtonItem *trashButt = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(deleteHaiku)];
    [trashButt setStyle : UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
    UIBarButtonItem *editButt = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editHaiku)];
    [trashButt setTintColor : self.userInfo.screenColorTrans];
    [editButt setTintColor : self.userInfo.screenColorTrans];
    [buttons addObject:editButt];
    [buttons addObject:trashButt];
}

            //Add the buttons to the nav bar.

[buttons addObject:flex];
[buttons addObject:send];
self.bar.items=buttons;
[self.view addSubview:self.bar];

            //Fade navigation bar: first delay, so that buttons are pressable, then fade.

double delayInSeconds = 3.5;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.bar.alpha = 0;
                     }];
});
}
```

It's not errors in the selector methods--I know this because if I replace `share` with a method `blahBlah` whose only code is to `NSLog` "Yup", it still doesn't do it.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to get some more context? The problem must exist elsewhere. Where are your methods being declared? What is the type of this object?

Comment: I think the problem exists somewhere else, but rather than spend more time hunting for it I'm going to go back to earlier code for now that was slightly less elegant but that I know worked.

Comment: But then the code will be forever a mystery! :P

Answer (score 2):

Try adding your methods like deleteHaiku,share,editHaiku just above the method "createToolbar" or viewdidload.I just tested it out,by pasting your above code into my viewdidload instead of createToolbar.It works.Here is the screeshot.Let me know if it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Hmm.  I tried that, but nothing doing.  It just doesn't make any sense.  So for now I've gone back to an earlier version of the code that I remember working.  It uses a UINavigationBar instead of a UIToolbar.  I think it's less elegant, but at least it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the action methods to include the sender as an argument, i.e. change

```
- (void) share;
```

to

```
- (void) share:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
```

and change where you set up the action as well, i.e. change

```
@selector(share)
```

to

```
@selector(share:)
```

Comment: Alas, that didn't do it.  I'm sure that the problem is somewhere else, so rather than continue to hunt I'm just going to go back to earlier code that was a little less elegant but that I know worked.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check you apps window is set properly something like in you apps delegate:

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Try this code.